# Как считать строку

Tags: c++

Я в консоль ввожу строку *age 22*

```
    string msg;
    cin >> msg;
    if (msg.compare("age") == 0)
    {
        char str[20];
        int i;

        sscanf(msg.c_str(), "%s %d", str, &i);
        printf("%s -> %d\n", str, i);
    }
```

слово age выводит правильно, а в цифрах мусор, помогите, как это можно  реализовать

Comment: Так у вас же в `msg` одно слово, без числа. Будь там число, `compare` бы не прошел. Число надо отдельно читать `cin >>`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat а как мне переписать код, чтобы я мог поймать число и слово и вывести

Comment: Используйте `getline` для чтения всей строки.

Comment: @Julji, делайте проще:  string msg;
    int i;
    cin >> msg >> i;    
    if (msg == "age")
        printf("%s -> %d\n", msg.c_str(), i);

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию строка из потока считывается до разделителя, т.е. в том числе до пробела. Поэтому нужно считать строку, а потом ещё число.

```
    int i;
    string msg;
    cin >> msg >> i;
    cout<< msg << " -> " << i;
```

Или считывать всю строку (до символа '\n') функцией 'getline()', и дальше форматировать как у вас в коде.

```
int i;
    string msg;
    char str[20];
  
    getline(cin, msg);
    sscanf(msg.c_str(), "%s %d", str, &i);
    printf("%s -> %d\n", str, i);
```